# Barcode Scanner input wihtou camera

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build an barcode scanner app using react-native.

I'm trying to use react-native-keyevent but, until now, no luck. Below the code of my component.

```
import React from 'react';
import KeyEvent from 'react-native-keyevent';

export default class ScannerKey extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ScannerKey MOUNTED');
        KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
            console.log(keyEvent);
        });
        // KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyEvent) => {
        //     console.log(keyEvent);
        // });
        // KeyEvent.onKeyMultipleListener((keyEvent) => {
        //     console.log(keyEvent);
        // });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what the expected result would be, and what the real result is.

Comment: Did you found any solution on this ?